# NLog database-logging giving system.argumentexception unable to find the requested .net framework data provider it may not be installed

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, nlog

I've added NLog to log to database to my Windows Service Application. When I init the logger with `private readonly Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();` I get `system.argumentexception unable to find the requested .net framework data provider it may not be installed`.

My `connectionString` in App.config:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DbEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=x.database.windows.net;initial catalog=db;persist security info=True;user id=x;password=x;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

In NLog.config:

```
<targets>

    <target name="database" xsi:type="Database">

      <connectionStringName>DbEntities</connectionStringName>
      <commandText>
        insert into dbo.Log (Application, Logged, Level, Message, Logger, CallSite, Exception) values (@Application, @Logged, @Level, @Message,@Logger, @Callsite, @Exception);
      </commandText>

      <parameter name="@application" layout="app" />
      <parameter name="@logged" layout="${date}" />
      <parameter name="@level" layout="${level}" />
      <parameter name="@message" layout="${message}" />

      <parameter name="@logger" layout="${logger}" />
      <parameter name="@callSite" layout="${callsite}" />
      <parameter name="@exception" layout="${exception:tostring}" />
    </target>

  </targets>
```

Under references I have `EntityFramework` and `EntityFramework.SqlServer`.

How can I fix this issue? I tried re-installting EntityFramework. I tried running my application in 32bit mode.

For all my other applications I never had an issue adding NLog like this.

Thank you.

Comment: What version of NLog are you using? Have you checked the InternalLogger https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging ?

Comment: @RolfKristensen I have the latest version 4.5.3. The internal log shows 2018-04-27 09:36:52.9149 Error Error initializing target 'Database Target[database]'. Exception: System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
   at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName)
   at NLog.Targets.DatabaseTarget.InitializeTarget()
   at NLog.Targets.Target.Initialize(LoggingConfiguration configuration)

Comment: What does the debugger show if you add `DbProviderFactories.GetFactoryClasses().Rows` to a debug-watch, and expand to show "Results View". Is there an item where its ItemArray-property contains the value `System.Data.SqlClient`?